# Cygwin make error : *** target pattern contains no `%'

Tags: cygwin, makefile

I got this error while (re)building, using cygwin make.exe version :3.81.

```
Error : *** target pattern contains no `%'.
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This error is due to a presence of a `":"`. Therefore it no longer supports windows paths. 
You need to download version 3.80 and replace the `make.exe` in the `\bin` directory.

Apparently it needs `cygintl12.dll` too.

Comment: +1: I came to this error from a different starting point (trying to compile using cmake & make 3.81 on Ubuntu). But your answer helped my nevertheless... The name of the parent of my build directory contained a ':'. After reading your answer I renamed it...assuming this somehow causes trouble in make...and it worked!

Comment: Changing the environment variable paths to unix compatible paths worked for me. I found the following links helpful: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage

Comment: @Leco - can you please add your solution as a separate answer? (with more details)

Comment: @Reno Sure thing. Give me a few days or so and I'll add it.

Answer (score 27):

- rollback to make 3.80 ([Geant4](http://geant4.web.cern.ch/geant4/support/windows_note.shtml))

  - `cd /usr/bin`
  - `mv make.exe make_381.exe`
  - `wget http://geant4.cern.ch/support/extras/cygwin/make.exe`
  - `chmod +x make.exe`
- install `libintl2` from cygwin setup for the required `cygintl-2.dll`

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error when trying to build a project on Linux or OSX, that was previously built on a Windows machine and had some **.o.d** files hanging around in the output folder.

Once I manually deleted the **.o.d** files the problem was resolved. Apparently the "Clean" command of my IDE (CodeLite in this case) wasn't deleting the **.o.d** files.

Comment: totally saved me.
I had my code running fine on Windows but not on OSX. After deleting files my idk-build clean command worked and after that idk-build also worked.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely due to the presence of a colon following a drive letter. For example consider

```
build : $(NativeHeaders)/*
```

If

```
NativeHeaders=../../../cpp/generated
```

then all is well, but

```
NativeHeaders=C:/dev/folder/cpp/generated
```

results in the error that you get.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this error because I didn't have a Tab (\t) character at the beginning of my commands. I had expandtab in my vim set so it was replacing a tab character with 4 spaces. When I turned that off and changed spaces to a tab it was fixed

Comment: I had the same problem in a makefile in OSX

Answer (score 2):

I had the `target pattern contains no '%'` error while building with the Android NDK using cygwin.

I found the following link helpful:

> [Errors Generated by Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html)
>
> - ‘missing target pattern. Stop.’
> - ‘multiple target patterns. Stop.’
> - ‘target pattern contains no `%'. Stop.’
> - ‘mixed implicit and static pattern rules. Stop.’
>
> These are generated for malformed static pattern rules. The first means there’s no pattern in the target section of the rule; the second means there are multiple patterns in the target section; the third means the target doesn’t contain a pattern character (%); and the fourth means that all three parts of the static pattern rule contain pattern characters (%)–only the first two parts should. If you see these errors and you aren’t trying to create a static pattern rule, ***check the value of any variables in your target and prerequisite lists to be sure they do not contain colons.*** See [Syntax of Static Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage).

And so, my solution included changing my system variables from Windows format to Unix format like so:

- Instead of `C:\Android\android-ndk-r10c`, I used `/cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r10c` for the NDK path.

Similarly, I changed the NDK project path to `/cygdrive/c/Android/project/src/main/jni`.

Comment: So you didn't figure out how to fix the paths used by make itself? This issue also occurs when make builds a list of files, and it appears that list of files is not fixed to be usable in a target.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using CMake under Cygwin when I got this error. It turned out the Windows version of CMake was executed. Subsequently, Windows paths were used in the make file. I installed Cygwin's version of CMake through the setup program and got it working.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on Linux when the build directory contained a ":" caused by doing a mercurial checkout which created a directory named "server:port".

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the following in my make file to be compatible with Make_381:
before:
ARDUINO_BASE_DIR = C:\programs/arduino

now:
ARDUINO_BASE_DIR = \\programs/arduino

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you're running Eclipse C/C++ and referencing files from Cygwin under Windows, make sure c:/cygwin/bin or c:/cygwin64/bin comes after your preferred compiler tools in your Windows Path environment.

Example:
    Path = ;C:\yagarto\bin;C:\yagarto-tools\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin;

After making the changes, exit Eclipse and restart for it to take effect (simply restarting Eclipse without exiting won't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, obj folder was probably corrupted and I was getting this error. Manually deleted obj folder. Then ndk-build completed fine.