# android ndk-build error

Tags: android, android-ndk, tesseract

I am trying to build tesseract for android.
I have put tesseract in samples folder as

`C:\Android_NDK\android-ndk-r8\samples\tesseract` 
with in `tesseract` folder I have `tesseract-3.00` folder, `leptonlib-1.66` folder and `libjpeg` folder.
Whenever I try to build the code using ndk-build.
I get error as

`C:/Android_NDK/android-ndk-r8/build/core/build-binary.mk:240: *** target pattern
 contains no '%'. Stop.`

I use ndk-build like this in Command Prompt
`C:\Android_NDK\android-ndk-r8\samples\tesseract\jni>C:\Android_NDK\android-ndk-r8/ndk-build`

`Application.mk` file contents in tesseract/jni  folder
    `# ARMv7 is significanly faster due to the use of the hardware FPU

     APP_STL := gnustl_static

     APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a

     APP_OPTIM := release

     APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions -frtti`

```
 Android.mk file contents in tesseract/jni folder  
# NOTE: You must set these variables to their respective source paths before
# compiling. For example, set LEPTONICA_PATH to the directory containing
# the Leptonica configure file and source folders. Directories must be
# root-relative, e.g. TESSERACT_PATH := /home/username/tesseract-3.00
#
# To set the variables, you can run the following shell commands:
# export TESSERACT_PATH=<path-to-tesseract>
# export LEPTONICA_PATH=<path-to-leptonica>
# export LIBJPEG_PATH=<path-to-libjpeg>
#
# Or you can fill out and uncomment the following definitions:
# TESSERACT_PATH := <path-to-tesseract>
# LEPTONICA_PATH := <path-to-leptonica>
# LIBJPEG_PATH := <path-to-libjpeg>

ifeq "$(TESSERACT_PATH)" ""
  $(error You must set the TESSERACT_PATH variable to the Tesseract source \
      directory. See README and jni/Android.mk for details)
endif

ifeq "$(LEPTONICA_PATH)" ""
  $(error You must set the LEPTONICA_PATH variable to the Leptonica source \
      directory. See README and jni/Android.mk for details)
endif

ifeq "$(LIBJPEG_PATH)" ""
  $(error You must set the LIBJPEG_PATH variable to the Android JPEG \
      source directory. See README and jni/Android.mk for details)
endif

# Just build the Android.mk files in the subdirs
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles) $(LIBJPEG_PATH)/Android.mk
```

Tried with Cygwin but the same problem.

Looking forward to your reply.

thanks.

Comment: can you post your mk file so we get to see more info.

Comment: @codetiger I have attached mk file details.

Comment: Please checkout this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601516/cygwin-make-error-target-pattern-contains-no) and a [forum post](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/334530/target-pattern-contains-no-.-stop). Your error seems to be related to ':' symbol in Windows paths which is treated like a pattern match

Comment: @AndreyErmakov how can we avoid ':' symbol in Windows?

Answer (score 2):

I think you not added below code to your buid.gradle file .This solution fo android studio

```
 sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
}
```