# android studio ndk error: *** target pattern contains no `%'. Stop

Tags: android, android-ndk, gradle, android-studio

i have followed this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okLKfxfbz40) to integrate ndk to my project. But after finished setup this error occurs when compiling. please help me to solve this error.

using
android studio v0.5.7
ndk android_ndk_r9b

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155054/android-ndk-build-error

Comment: there is no answer in this link

Comment: This link has reference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601516/cygwin-make-error-target-pattern-contains-no, which has answer

Comment: most of the solutions are based on cygwin only. Not for android studio or ndk. According to the answers shall i change the make.exe in this android ndk folder ..\androidndkr9b\prebuilt\windows\bin. thanks for your reply.

Comment: Have you tried other suggestion from my first link (removing tab characters, o.d. files, etc)?

Comment: There is no o.d. files in my android studio project folder. And also there is no space or tab characters in my project path or ndk path.

Comment: please post your `build.gradle` file and the complete build output.

Comment: Could you post more info? Maybe mk file, S.O or something else?

Comment: @Piperoman: in *gradle*, the `.mk` files are generated on the fly

Comment: Well, I had the issue once and I solved checking paths, windows use \ but Linux use /, could be something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. https://github.com/prasaathviki/androidndksample Herewith i have attached my sample project please verify it.

Comment: @OP Were you able to make any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

Please switch to the latest Android-NDK (android-ndk-r10e in my case).

I had this issue with following config -
Eclipse luna, Android SDK & Android-ndk-r9b.

When I updated the NDK, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have not added the code below to your build.gradle file. This solution is for android-studio:

```
sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
}
```