# Cant run rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am just getting started with ruby on rails, after installing rails executing many commands on the console, i tried to run rails server with the command `rails server` but gets an error about not loading coffee-rails, i tried the command `gem install coffee-rails` i got

```
    gem install coffee-rails
    Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing coffee-rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20140724-4244-v083ym.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make  clean
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.
1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/js
on-1.8.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: and do not run under Windows, use Unix ;)

Comment: I second do not use Windows.  You will consistently run into problems that you won't under mac/linux/unix.  I bought a macbook just for rails programming and its been so much nicer.

Comment: yeah, windows is crappy, will switch to unix at any chance  ...

Answer (score 1):

RubyGems 2.4.1 will not build native extensions in Ruby version 1.9.3 and earlier on Windows.

You will need to downgrade RubyGems to 1.8.29.
To do this run the following command:

```
gem update --system 1.8.29
```

Check gem version:

```
gem -v
1.8.29
```

Now try your command again:

```
gem install coffee-rails
```

ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyinstaller/k19SeJijpKU/discussion

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601516/cygwin-make-error-target-pattern-contains-no) - they seem to have had the same trouble and had to use an older version of make.